# Cassandra tmpdir change location

Tags: java, database, cassandra, jvm

Cassandra is failing to start if `/tmp` is set as `noexec`, which is pretty much default these days:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.memory.MemoryUtil.allocate(MemoryUtil.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.<init>(Memory.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.allocate(Memory.java:97) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummary$IndexSummarySerializer.deserialize(IndexSummary.java:323) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.loadSummary(SSTableReader.java:836) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:692) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.load(SSTableReader.java:664) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:458) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:363) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$4.run(SSTableReader.java:501) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

If I remove the `noexec` flag from the `/var/tmp` mount *Cassandra* starts up properly. I've tried a number of methods to change the location of the tmpdir in the `cassandra-env.sh` file:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djna.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
```

I haven't used these all at once, of course, these are solutions I've found on the internet, but none seem to work. I even tried exporting `TMPDIR` at the start of the `cassandra-env.sh` file, but to no avail. It always fails with the same message.

I think it's a bad idea to leave `/tmp` without the noexec flag, security-wise. I'm obviously missing something basic here. How do I set the tmpdir to be `/home/cassandra/tmp` or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, looks like **both** options have to be present in the `cassandra-env.sh` file:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djna.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp"
```

Comment: Should these JVM_OPTS not be in the jvm.options/ jvm-server.options file instead?

Answer (score 0):

I had to also add a TMPDIR environment variable to the `cassandra-env.sh` file.  For example:

export TMPDIR=/home/cassandra/tmp